# Finding average of one column based on the average values from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Upon executing this code, I get twelve rows of data with a new column `A1`. I want a functionality such, that for all "1" appearing in `A1`, I should get an average of the corresponding Sepal.Length values,similarly for "2" and "3" and the assign the three average values to a new vector. So in all, a vector with three average values based on the requirement above.

```
iris1 = iris[1:12,]
a = data.frame(A1=rep(1,4))
b = data.frame(A1=rep(2,4))
c = data.frame(A1 = rep(3,4))
abc = rbind(a,b,c)
abc
iris2 = data.frame(abc,iris1)
View(iris2)
```

Comment: Do you mean group by A1, and get mean of Sepal.Length for every row? What is the expected output?

Comment: e.g. `sapply(split(iris2$Sepal.Length, iris2$A1), mean)` or `aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ A1, iris2, mean)`?

Comment: Thanks Axeman, solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: Please help me with link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972729/making-a-stacked-bar-plot-based-on-ranges-in-r-and-plotly/46972927?noredirect=1#comment80893631_46972927

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
library(dplyr)
iris2 %>% group_by(A1) %>% summarise(Avg = mean(Sepal.Length,na.rm = TRUE))
```

and if you really just want the vector with the Averages

```
iris2 %>% group_by(A1) %>% summarise(Avg = mean(Sepal.Length,na.rm = TRUE)) %>% `$`(Avg)
```

Comment: Also, see `dplyr::pull` instead of `.$Avg`.

Comment: Thanks Bertil, I'll consider this, appreciate your help.