# Making a stacked bar plot based on ranges in R and plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I want to create a stacked bar chart in R and plotly using iris dataset. In the x-axis, I want to set limits like iris_limits below in the code and the y-axis should contain all the Sepal.Length values which fit into these ranges. I want to pass the values as a single vector. Also, if the limits can be made dynamic by understanding the range of the Sepal.Length instead of hard coding it, please help. I have written a basic script with values to give you an idea. Thanks.

```
library(plotly)
iris_limits <- c("1-4", "4-6", "6-8")
sepal <- c(2.4,5.4,7.1)
data <- data.frame(iris_limits, sepal)
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~iris_limits, y = ~sepal, type = 'bar', name = 
'Sepal') %>%
layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')
p
```

Comment: What is being stacked for each `Sepal.Length` group?  `Species`?

Comment: iris_limits <- c("1-4", "4-6", "6-8"), these ranges, and the sepal.length value should fall in these ranges.

Comment: So one bar, the bar count is divided (stacked) based on Sepal.Length range?

Comment: In the x-axis, I need it as "1-3","3-6","6-9". If this can be generated dynamically without hard coding it. Also, I want to pass iris$Sepal.Length as one vector from which every value of Sepal.Length is a bar which should fall into the one of the range above. Thus making it a stacked bar chart.  This is my need?

Comment: @Djork, please help me with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278387/creating-a-horizontal-bar-chart-in-r-to-display-sequence-of-activities?noredirect=1#comment81507641_47278387

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried my best to understand.  First dividing the sepal length to the desired categories `iris_limits`: "1-3","3-6","6-9"

```
iris$iris_limits <- cut(iris$Sepal.Length, c(1,3,6,9))
```

Note: no sepal length is in between 1-3, so you only have 2 groups.

Then you want each sepal length limit as a separate bar on the x axis, and each individual sepal length falling into category to be bar stacked onto each other? You linked to a stack bar chart with varying color for the stacked bars, is this what you want?

Create an ID for each sepal length:

```
iris$ID <- factor(1:nrow(iris))
```

Plot, set `color=~ID` if you want different colors for the stacked bars:

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(iris, x = ~iris_limits, y = ~Sepal.Length, type = 'bar', color=~ID) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'stack')
```

[image]

**EDITED** For version that is not stacked but grouped by `iris_limits`, I switched to `ggplot2` to make use of `facet_wrap` functionality to segregate by `iris_limits`, then use `ggplotly`.

```
gg <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=ID, y=Sepal.Length, fill=iris_limits)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~iris_limits, scales="free_x", labeller=label_both) +
  theme_minimal() + xlab("") + ylab("Sepal Length") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

**EDITED: Re: Changing legend title and tooltip display**

To change the legend title, use `labs`. Here it was also necessary to change the `legend.title` font size under `theme` to fit the `ggplotly` margins.

To change the tooltip text, add `text` parameter to `aes` to create desired character string, then define `aes` values to be displayed in `tooltip` in `ggplotly`.

```
gg <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=ID, y=Sepal.Length, fill=iris_limits,
                   text=paste("Sepal Length:", Sepal.Length, "cm"))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~iris_limits, scales="free_x") +
  theme_minimal() + xlab("") + ylab("Sepal Length (cm)") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), legend.title=element_text(size=10)) +
  labs(fill="Sepal \nLength (cm)")
ggplotly(gg, tooltip=c("x", "text"))
```

Comment: Very nice but nearly close, these sepal.length limits as a separate bar on the x axis should be vertical to x-axis and not parallel, and second, the right slider is not needed, kindly help.

Comment: If it's vertical to the x-axis then it's not a stacked bar, and you really want multiple bars that are grouped by sepal length limits?

Comment: yes multiple bars, like a grouped bar chart. See this link here. M sorry but I thought grouped and stacked to be same.                                 
https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/

Comment: Big thanks Djork, really really appreciate your help.

Comment: @AshminKaul It's a nice practice to upvote the answer along with marking answered!

Comment: @Djork, this plot has helped me immensely. I need your help with little two tweaks:                                                                                                          1. Firstly,  The labels iris_limits on top of plots and axes, I want to rename them,                                                                                            2. Also when we hover on the plot, I want to assign "cm" to Sepal.Length in the tooltip. Thanks and please help.

Comment: Hmm, when I run it, I am not able to see "cm" besides Sepal.Length and also when I zoom the plot, Sepal.Length on Y-axis dissappears.

Comment: Please see the bottom edit, I just updated it. It works for me.

Comment: Yes, thanks, @Djork, please help me with this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018157/updating-multiple-infobox-using-plotly-click-in-r-and-plotly

Comment: Hi @Djork, I want to calculate how many number of bars that are present in these two ranges above. Just want to find the number, please help.

Comment: @Djork, Hi, I require your help with this post, please check, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920689/displaying-data-in-the-chart-based-on-plotly-click-in-r-shiny/47921511#47921511

Comment: @Djork, I need your help to integrate the js code with R, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162029/integrating-the-js-code-in-r-to-make-the-visnetwork-edges-curved

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cut`:

```
library(plotly)
iris$iris_limits <- as.numeric(cut(iris$Sepal.Length,3))
p <- plot_ly(iris, x = ~iris_limits, y = ~Sepal.Length, type = 'bar', name = 
               'Sepal') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'group')
p
```

[image]

The grouping details:

```
> iris$Sepal.Length[iris$iris_limits==1]
 [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.6 5.0 4.4 4.9 5.4 4.8 4.8 4.3 5.4 5.1 5.1 5.4 5.1 4.6 5.1 4.8 5.0 5.0 5.2 5.2 4.7 4.8
[29] 5.4 5.2 5.5 4.9 5.0 5.5 4.9 4.4 5.1 5.0 4.5 4.4 5.0 5.1 4.8 5.1 4.6 5.3 5.0 5.5 4.9 5.2 5.0 5.5 5.5 5.4 5.5 5.5
[57] 5.0 5.1 4.9
> iris$Sepal.Length[iris$iris_limits==2]
 [1] 5.8 5.7 5.7 6.4 6.5 5.7 6.3 6.6 5.9 6.0 6.1 5.6 6.7 5.6 5.8 6.2 5.6 5.9 6.1 6.3 6.1 6.4 6.6 6.7 6.0 5.7 5.8 6.0
[29] 6.0 6.7 6.3 5.6 6.1 5.8 5.6 5.7 5.7 6.2 5.7 6.3 5.8 6.3 6.5 6.7 6.5 6.4 5.7 5.8 6.4 6.5 6.0 5.6 6.3 6.7 6.2 6.1
[57] 6.4 6.4 6.3 6.1 6.3 6.4 6.0 6.7 5.8 6.7 6.7 6.3 6.5 6.2 5.9
> iris$Sepal.Length[iris$iris_limits==3]
 [1] 7.0 6.9 6.8 7.1 7.6 7.3 7.2 6.8 7.7 7.7 6.9 7.7 7.2 7.2 7.4 7.9 7.7 6.9 6.9 6.8
>
```

Comment: Hi amrrs, thanks but this is very different, I need ranges in x-axes like "1-3","3-6","6-9", and fit  all the sepal.length values in that range. each sepal.length value should represent a bar. thanks again.

Comment: Did you try to hover it? that's what it does.

Comment: In your x-axis, I see 1,2, and 3, I need it as "1-3","3-6","6-9". Also, I want to pass iris$Sepal.Length as one vector from which every value of Sepal.Length is a bar which should fall into the one of the range above. Thus making it a stacked bar chart. This is my need?

Comment: https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/#stacked-bar-chart                                             , the grouped bar chart in this link may help.

Comment: I appreciate your help amrrs, thank you for your help.

Comment: @AshminKaul I meant it for the actual answer.

Comment: I am trying to update multple widgets using plotly_click, please help me with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018157/updating-multiple-infobox-using-plotly-click-in-r-and-plotly